# Запрос INSERT OR REPLACE

Tags: sql, oracle

Формирую запрос на вставку данных в базу.

```
INSERT OR REPLACE 
INTO ADDFIELDS (ADDFIELDID, DESCRIPTION, FIELDTYPE) 
VALUES(0, dfgresg, строка)
```

Но в моем случае это оказалось не верно, вопрос, как можно организовать процесс проверки наличия данных в таблице, грубо говоря проверяем есть ли такие даныне уже существуют, тогда их просто изменяем типа Udpate, если данных таких нет тогда INsert.

Comment: Пример из интернетов: `INSERT INTO tbl SET name= 'Товар 11', uc='000009' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name= 'Товар 11'`

Comment: Используйте [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9017.htm#SQLRF01606).

Comment: @Adokenai Для какой RDBMS Вы нашли этот "пример из Интернетов"?

Answer (score 2):

Для это есть [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F). Наглядный и воспроизводимый пример покажет как он работает:

```sql
create table fields as
    select 0 id, 'dummy field' memo, 'dummy type' type from dual union all
    select 1, 'field1', 'char' from dual 
/
merge into fields t using (
    with source (id, memo, type) as (
        select 0, null,     null   from dual union all
        select 1, 'field1', 'date' from dual union all
        select 2, 'field2', 'char' from dual) select * from source
) s on (s.id = t.id)
when not matched then 
    insert values (s.id, s.memo, s.type)
when matched then 
    update set t.memo = s.memo, t.type = s.type
    delete where id = 0
/
```

Реззультат запроса до и после:

```sql
select * from fields
/
        ID MEMO        TYPE      
---------- ----------- ----------
         0 dummy field dummy type
         1 field1      char      
--->>> after
         1 field1      date      
         2 field2      char
```